# Is there any way to close Magnific when a Vimeo video has finished playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

Hoping you can help me. I have a Magnific iframe popup that plays a Vimeo video. However, once it is finished, I'd like to automatically close the popup. Is this even possible via this plugin?

My current (working code):

```
$vimeo.magnificPopup({

    closeBtnInside: false,
    showCloseBtn: false,
    disableOn: 0,
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 0,
    preloader: true,
    fixedContentPos: false,
    callbacks: {

        beforeOpen: function() {
            cache.$main.addClass('playing');
        },

        open: function() {
                $(this.currItem.el).closest('.project__item').toggleClass('playing');
        },

        close: function() {
            $('.project__item').removeClass('playing');
        },

        afterClose: function() {
            cache.$main.removeClass('playing');
        }

    }

});
```

I have searched the web and the official Magnific API documentation to no success.

Any help or a nod in the right direction appreciated.

Many thanks,
Mikey.

Answer (score 2):

Add iframe markup:

```
$vimeo.magnificPopup({

    closeBtnInside: false,
    showCloseBtn: false,
    disableOn: 0,
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 0,
    preloader: true,
    fixedContentPos: false,


   iframe: {
  markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
            '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
            '<iframe id="player1" class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
          '</div>', // HTML markup of popup, `mfp-close` will be replaced by the close button

  patterns: {
    youtube: {
      index: 'youtube.com/', // String that detects type of video (in this case YouTube). Simply via url.indexOf(index).

      id: 'v=', // String that splits URL in a two parts, second part should be %id%
      // Or null - full URL will be returned
      // Or a function that should return %id%, for example:
      // id: function(url) { return 'parsed id'; } 

      src: '//www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1' // URL that will be set as a source for iframe. 
    },
    callbacks: {

        beforeOpen: function() {
            cache.$main.addClass('playing');
        },

        open: function() {
                $(this.currItem.el).closest('.project__item').toggleClass('playing');
        },

        close: function() {
            $('.project__item').removeClass('playing');
        },

        afterClose: function() {
            cache.$main.removeClass('playing');
        }

    }

});
```

Add event to your player:

```
var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);

player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
```

"onFinish" is function that will close your magnificPopup :

```
  var onFinish = function(){
       $vimeo.magnificPopup.close();
    }
```

Comment: To what part of the HTML does the #player1 exactly relate to? The iframe itself?

Comment: This is id of your iframe

Comment: for example: <iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?api=1&player_id=player1" width="630" height="354" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: The iframe is generated by Magnific and it doesn't have an ID. It does have a class name though of .mfp-iframe

Comment: use markup property :          iframe: {
  markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
            '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
            '<iframe id="player1" class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
          '</div>', // HTML markup of popup, `mfp-close` will be replaced by the close button

Comment: In addition you must wait for iframe finishing render and after that add the event for this

Comment: player.addEvent('finish', onFinish); never seems to execute. No errors. If I use player.addEvent('ready', onFinish); it will fire. I'm not sure why?